Problem with flashcards height
I am looking to adjust the size of my flashcards using the flashcards package. However, I am encountering an issue when I try to add a title to my flashcard. As you can see, adding the title reduces the height of the front of the flashcard, but not the back. Could you assist me with this, please?
\documentclass[frame,avery5371,12pt]{flashcards}
    
\setlength{\cardheight}{3in}
\setlength{\cardwidth}{3.5in}

\cardfrontstyle[\large]{headings}
\cardbackstyle[\large]{plain}


\begin{document}

\begin{flashcard}[titre ]{question 1}

réponse 1

\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}{question 2}

réponse 2

\end{flashcard}


\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!
